# jQuery hover / slideDown problem

Tags: jquery, hover

I am fairly using simple jquery method to a dropdown. But the code isnt working in firefox 3.5 and lower nor opera. Is their an alternative to these browsers for hover or slideDown?? Its working great on webkit, firefox 3.6 up and IE8+

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <ul> <!-- this is the dropdown part -->
      <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
    </ul> <!-- end dropdown -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#menu li').hover(
    function () {
        $('ul', this).slideDown(250);
    },
    function () {
        $('ul', this).slideUp(250);         
    }
);
```

Comment: Why do you have a list inside a list? Which li element do you wish to slide up? The outter one, the inner one or both?

Comment: @Razor Storm: I'm assuming it's an accordion menu. But I could be wrong. Define 'not working.' Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @Razor Storm its not an accordion, its a dropdown menu and i want to show the ul inside the first li .. wanted to keep the html rule of using ul :) .. i just edited the question with comments...

Comment: @David Thomas no erros, not the below answer simply worked.. really confusing, hehe :) maybe i have lots of other jquery stuff in the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An adaptation of your code works perfectly well, for me, in both Chromium 11 and Firefox 4 (Ubuntu 11.04):

```
$('#menu > li:has("ul")').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu3xG/1/).

Notes:

- `$('#menu > li:has("ul")')` is just a more specific selector (it targets only immediate descendants of the `#menu` element, that are *both* `li` elements *and* contain a `ul` element).
- `$(this).find('ul')` is the same as your context selector (`$('ul,this)`) except that internally jQuery calls the `$(this).find()` method anyway:

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('span')`.

Reference:

- [Selector context at the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context).